# Camel RabbitMQ DLQ implementation with autoAck true

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a very simple requirement of

1. On some exceptions, requeue the message
2. On certain other exceptions, send to [DLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue)

My route is
RabbitMQ → [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) validations → database validations → destination RabbitMQ

For case 1, my Camel exception route is:

```
onException(IOException.class)
                // Requeue for processing again
                .setHeader("rabbitmq.REQUEUE", constant(Boolean.TRUE))
                .removeHeaders("*")
                .bean(<Do some stuff>)
                .handled(true)
                .end();
```

For case 2, my Camel exception route is

```
onException(JsonPathException.class, PathNotFoundException.class)
                .setHeader("rabbitmq.REQUEUE", constant(Boolean.FALSE))
                .handled(true)
                .end()
```

My basic Camel route is something like:

```
from(eventConsumerEndpoint)
                .filter().method(<validation>)
                .bean(<db fetch>)
                .filter().method(<db validation>)
                .removeHeaders("*")
                .to(eventConsumerDestination)
                .end();
```

Now I have not used autoAck=false anywhere. My URI is something like:

```
rabbitmq://localhost:5672/events?autoDelete=false&deadLetterExchange=events&deadLetterExchangeType=topic&deadLetterQueue=dlq.xxx.yyy&deadLetterRoutingKey=evt.xxx.dead&exchangeType=topic&password=xxxxxx&queue=central-queue&username=guest&vhost=%2F
```

So neither of my cases works - no requeue on IOException, no DLQ on JsonPath exception. So is this all because of autoAck? I don’t want to handle acknowledgement at all, so is it possible to do this with autoAck false?

Comment: **There is no requeue with auto-ack.** Once the message is delivered, the broker acks it and forgets about it. Beyond that, I don't know enough to provide an answer.

Comment: @theMayer Thanks. You mean requeue with autoAck set to true right?

Comment: I haven’t a clue what you’re talking about. Basic.Reject allows you to specify requeue. AutoAck is set before the messages arrive at the consumer.

Comment: @theMayer You said "There is no requeue with auto-ack". I asked if you made this statement in the light of autoAck being true, is all.

Comment: Well, yes, "with auto ack" can be seen as "auto ack = true."

Comment: What is "dlq"? "DLQ"? [Dead letter queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue)?

Answer (score 1):

### With JMS transactions (SESSION_TRANSACTED)

If you want to reprocess the same message again, you must consume messages transactionally and **not handle the error**. Only if the Camel route "fails", the broker transaction is rolled back and the message is **immediately** delivered again by the broker (before any other message is consumed).

I don't know RabbitMQ, but on ActiveMQ you can configure redeliveries. If **all retries fail**, the message is automatically **sent to the DLQ** by the broker.

However, a typical problem is, that an immediate reprocessing does not help because it would simply fail again because the **problem still exists**.

### Without JMS transactions (AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

If you don't use JMS transactions then you have no redeliveries and therefore no DLQ delivery through the broker. A message you consumed is immediately committed on the broker and therefore done.

That means **you have to do it "manually"** with Camel. You can do so by handle the error as you do and simply add a `.to()` in your `onException` block to send the failed message to another queue.

However, if an error occurs that is not handled in your routes (for example an error in your `onException` block), the **message is lost**! Because with AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE the broker cannot redeliver the message again.

Comment: What is the impact of autoAck? I am not concerned about the redelivery count - all I want is to either requeue or send to dlq but without autoAck as false. My question is - is that even possible?

Comment: I edited my answer to differ between autoAck and transacted. Hope this makes things clear for you.

Comment: OK, I get it. So I am on the latter half of your answer which means that it is safer to Auto Ack false and do the redelivery (what I call as requeue) or push to dlq on exceptions. So is there any other caveat to handle when I set autoAck to false (on the main path, ExchangePattern.InOnly is enough to ack right?

Comment: Transactional consumption is mostly configured on the ConnectionFactory to your broker. The exact configuration depends on your application setup. If you have a transaction manager in place, you can use it. If not you can use local JMS transactions of the broker. This is quite a big subject. To learn it from scratch I recommend Claus Ibsens book "Camel in Action" https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition